# "Show filter choices" link instead of actual values in a list column filter

Tags: 2010, list, filter

I have created an standard list with a few simple text columns.

Why can I not see the normal filter values of all columns?  Instead it shows a new "Show Filter choices" link (pic 1) which when clicked brings all the values above the column names (pic 2).

How can I make the filter simply shows all distinct values which I think is default behavior and have in many other list in our portal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a large list ? how many items ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comment above, when the list has over 500 items for performance reasons some fields will not display the available values and display "Show Filter Choices" instead.

If you wish you could try adding ?Filter=1 in the URL, which will show the available values by default. Not sure if it will work for you.

If you are familiar and comfortable working with Sharepoint Designer, you can also try the suggestions on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8dc026b0-2856-4719-8eb6-aab5f15c7995/by-default-needs-to-enable-show-filter-choices-in-sharepoint-2010-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) which will help you open the page and modify the DataView webpart.

As always, since this is related to performance it would be a good idea to check for negative side effects before actually implementing any workarounds. You will find AJAX suggestions too if you search online for "[sharepoint show filter choices](https://www.google.fi/search?q=sharepoint%20Show%20Filter%20Choices&oq=sharepoint%20Show%20Filter%20Choices&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60j0j69i60j0.5264j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)".