# Why is filtering on different columns show data while other displays "Show Filter Choices"

Tags: 2013

Sometimes when I click on the drop down box for a header it lists all of the information and I just click on the number I want.  Other times, I only can sort by ascending or descending unless I chose to show filter choices which takes a while but then I see all the numbers and can chose what I am looking for.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

When the list has over 500 items for performance reasons some fields will not display the available values and display "Show Filter Choices" instead.

["Show filter choices" link instead of actual values in a list column filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116660/show-filter-choices-link-instead-of-actual-values-in-a-list-column-filter)