# List filter with multiple selection for ID column

Tags: list, multi-select

In SharePoint 2016 I have a list that uses the ID column in the list view.

For all the other columns I can filter by using the checkboxes for multiple choices, but with the ID column I can not.
Does anyone have a workaround?

Please see the behavior of the ID column and another column.

[image: ID Column doesn't show the check boxes]

[image: All other columns do show the check boxes for multiple filtering choice]

Thanks,
Effy L.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is the number of items in the view. Reduce it to 500 and it should start working as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to answer your question well and has a workaround (*as well as some other suggestions*) that's easy to try by adding "?Filter=1" to the end of the list URL - ["Show filter choices" link instead of actual values in a list column filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116660/show-filter-choices-link-instead-of-actual-values-in-a-list-column-filter).

Hope this helps,

-Drew