# SharePoint 2013 list view web part show filter in each column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I found that there is an option to show a cool filter box in each column by chance(screenshot below)

[image]

when you click on "Show Filter Choices" on the dropdown.
[image]

I found that when you clicked on the "Show Filter Choices", the URL is changed to 
"https://teams.connect.xxx.com/sites/ruter/Pages/Roster_U2.aspx?Filter=1&View={583937A6-293B-419F-8F05-3EA7092915FB}#InplviewHash583937a6-293b-419f-8f05-3ea7092915fb=WebPartID%3D%7B583937A6--293B--419F--8F05--3EA7092915FB%7D"
My question is, what can I do to make the filter boxes always visible?

Answer (score 0):

When a SharePoint List gets to a certain size, around 500 items, some fields will no longer display a proper drop down for filter choices Instead, it will display “Show Filter Choices”.  Microsoft did this to prevent performance problems by showing >500 options to choose from.

If you wish you could try adding ?Filter=1 in the URL, which will show the available values by default.

Here are some articles for your reference:

https://thesharepointfarm.com/2010/09/sharepoint-list-filter-problems-or-show-filter-choices/

["Show filter choices" link instead of actual values in a list column filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116660/show-filter-choices-link-instead-of-actual-values-in-a-list-column-filter)