# Filter Choices not showing for single line of Text column in list view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view-threshold, sharepoint-list-filter, single-line-of-text

We have a document library in SharePoint 2013 on-premise with nearly 12k items(List View threshold limit was set to 50k items). There is a column with the name `Cust Name`(Indexed Column) of type `Single Line of Text`.

Filter Choices not showing for the Column.

[image]

The filters are working fine for the other single line of text columns(Indexed columns).

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if there are more than 500 unique values in a column, the column header filtering will display “Show Filter Choices” instead of the unique values in the column to avoid performance issues.

More references:

["Show filter choices" link instead of actual values in a list column filter](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116660/show-filter-choices-link-instead-of-actual-values-in-a-list-column-filter)

http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2012/11/sharepoint-list-show-filter-choices.html#.VVGfZGAfoiQ

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will check and update